# Vue Router interfering with Javascript fetch

Tags: vue.js, fetch, vue-router

I'm trying to use `fetch` in my Vue 2 project, but when I try to access `file.json` in the root directory, it instead loads the `index.html` *every time!* I have a strong feeling it's Vue router's fault.

So how can I prevent Vue router from redirecting my fetches???

Here is my `router.js`:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import Group from "../views/Group.vue";
import Computer from "../views/Computer.vue";
import NoComputer from "../views/NoComputer.vue";
import Error404 from "../views/404.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
{
  path: "/",
  name: "Home",
  component: Home
},
{
  path: "/group/:group",
  component: Group,
  props: true,
  children: [
  { path: '', component: NoComputer },
  {
    path: 'computer/:com',
    component: Computer,
    props: true,
  }
  ]
},
// always at bottom of list
{ path: '*', component: Error404 }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});

export default router;
```

And here is my fetching:

```js
async getComputers() {
    var res = await fetch("/file.json", {
        method: 'GET',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        redirect: 'error',
    });
    console.log(res.json());
},
```

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Vue Router issue. Vue CLI uses Webpack's `devServer`, which enables [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback). That returns `index.html` in place of any `404` responses. The `index.html` response implies the resource you requested (`file.json`) does not exist at the specified path.

If `file.json` is a static asset, ensure it exists in the `public` directory (i.e., at the root of it for `/file.json` to be found).